# How much microgravity is there on ISS due to tidal forces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, estimation, tidal-effect

I used the equation for the tidal force:

$$ F = \frac{2GMd}{r^3} $$

where $M$ is the mass of the Earth ($5.972 \times 10^{24}$ kg), $d$ is half the length of ISS ($50$ m), $r$ distance from center of Earth ($410+6371$ km).

I got 127 micrometres/s$^2$ for gravity on ISS due to tidal effects, it seems quite large did I do something wrong?

Comment: Quite large compared to this: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3902/ The equation you have would be for an observer falling freely towards Earth. What happens if you calculate if for a body moving in circular orbit?

Comment: @ChrisWhite  I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure of $d = 50$m that you've used is the length of the ISS crew module, but the ISS is arranged so that its length is (approximately) the same distance from the Earth:

[image: ISD]

To a first approximation there is no tidal force along the length of the ISS because it's all the same distance from the Earth so the gravitational acceleration doesn't change.

However the bottom of the ISS is nearer the Earth than the top and this will result in a tidal force. But the $d$ in your equation is the thickness of the ISS not its width. The module diameter is around $5$m ([or so Google assures me](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=iss%20module%20diameter)) so to calculate the tidal force across the module use $d = 5$m not $d = 50$m.